# Show only authors post except a single post ID

Tags: custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I am working with Wordpress, and I have a post type using ACF fields.

The fact is that I used a function in function.php to show only author's posts but I completely forgot that It wont show the ACFgroupfields

Here is my function

```
function posts_for_current_author($query) {
    global $user_level;

    if($query->is_admin && $user_level < 5) {
        global $user_ID;
        $query->set('author',  $user_ID);
        unset($user_ID);

    }
    unset($user_level);

    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'posts_for_current_author');
```

How to make an exception for an ID for a post ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late to respond to this. But what you could try is something like this.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'pre_check', 10, 2);
function pre_check($query) {
  global $user_ID;
  if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' ) && $query->query['post_type'] != 'acf-field-group' && $query->query['post_type'] != 'acf-field') {
    $query->set('author',  $user_ID);
  }

  return $query;
}
```

This way it will not list posts/pages other than what belongs to the author. And still display the ACF fields on the posts/pages itself.